# General SVG filter for multi-colored logos

Tags: css, svg, filter

I have several PNG-logos (one solid color, solid black, solid white, black + color). I want to make one filter for all logos so that they are solid white.

Solution #1 filter: brightness(1000) saturate(0); 
works good but does`t work on black logos

Solution #2 I tried to use feColorMatrix. But I could not find the matrices of one for all

Plz help!

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far (the markup).

Comment: There wouldn't be a single solution for this...you'd need multiple solutions depending on the image and the colors involved.

Comment: I found a solution, but it's not perfect. Edit in Photoshop - black on "almost black". and use filter: brightness(1000) saturate(0); Thanks!